# error: InvalidApnsCredential when sending ios push to Firebase, auth key and certificates are added

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I get an error saying from FCM when trying to send notification through APN as below:

```
multicast_id:213242345
success: 0,
failure: 1,
canonical_ids: 0,
results: [ { error: 'InvalidApnsCredential' } ]
```

I have integrated Apn auth key to FCM.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a team ID to Firebase console,
make sure it is same with the APP Prefix ID (team id) from Apple Provisioning file.